# How to access an aspx page located in a different project?

Tags: 2010, development, aspx

I have a SharePoint solution with an empty SharePoint project and an ASP.NET project. My ASP.NET project has an aspx page I would like to access. How can I access this page from my SharePoint project? E.g. Adding a link in Site Settings that will open it via the Feature Event Receiver of the SharePoint project?

Thanks!